# golang storing map to variable and do asserts

Tags: go, avi

I am trying to use [Avi Go SDK](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Crypto89/sdk/go@v0.0.0-20190910135836-56c48329b7ce#section-readme) to fetch a gslb configuration.

First initilizing a connection to the controller as below,

```
aviClient, err := clients.NewAviClient("mycontroller", "USER",
    session.SetPassword("PASSS"),
    session.SetTenant("TENANT"),
    session.SetInsecure)
if err != nil {
    t.Error(err)
}
```

Then trying to grab a gslb details as below,

```
//Fetch gslb
var obj interface{}
err = aviClient.AviSession.GetObjectByName("gslbservice", "mygslbname", &obj)
fmt.Printf("%v\n", obj)
```

and that print the details as below,

```
map[_last_modified:1650419741251661 controller_health_status_enabled:true created_by:null description:null domain_names:[xxxxxxxxxxxxx] down_response:map[type:GSLB_SERVICE_DOWN_RESPONSE_ALL_RECORDS] enabled:true groups:[map[algorithm:GSLB_ALGORITHM_ROUND_ROBIN members:[map[cluster_uuid:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx enabled:true fqdn:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ip:map[addr:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx type:V4] location:map[source:GSLB_LOCATION_SRC_INHERIT_FROM_SITE] ratio:1]] name:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx priority:10]] health_monitor_refs:[https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx] health_monitor_scope:GSLB_SERVICE_HEALTH_MONITOR_ALL_MEMBERS name:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx num_dns_ip:1 tenant_ref:https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ttl:30 url:https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx use_edns_client_subnet:true uuid:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx wildcard_match:false]
```

Now I would like to store that whole map to variable so that I can do asserts and test as below,

```
var obj1 interface{}    
appDeployment := aviClient.AviSession.GetObjectByName("gslbservice", "mygslbname", &obj1)
if err != nil {
    t.Error(err)
}
assert.Equal(t, appDeployment.domain_names, "mygslbname")
```

I get below error,

```
appDeployment.domain_names undefined (type error has no field or method domain_names)
```

Any assitance?
Or How do print any values from the map, for eg how to print ttl value from above map?

Comment: `appDeployment` is an error. Maybe you meant to write `obj1`?

Comment: in my other kubernetes project it works fine as below,

appDeployment, err := clientset.AppsV1().Deployments(namespace).Get(context.TODO(), tfVars.DeploymentName, v1.GetOptions{})
 if err != nil {
  t.Error(err)
 }
 assert.Equal(t, appDeployment.Spec.Template.Spec.ServiceAccountName, "myserviceaccount")

Comment: In your second code snippet, `GetObjectByName` is returning an error. In the last one, you are expecting an `appDeployment` from the same method.

Comment: sorry, I am not a regular programmer. Let me ask this. In second code snippet
I have a var called `obj` and then storing the output of aviClient.AviSession.GetObjectByName method in `err`
Then I am printing `obj` using `fmt.Printf("%v\n", obj)`
so what is in `err` ?

Comment: It would have any error response returned from that method call.

Comment: So the actual map output (which is the output of aviClient.AviSession.GetObjectByName) is stored at `obj` ?  When I do `fmt.Printf("%v\n", obj)`  why is that `"%v\n"` needed there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244070/discussion-between-simon-and-burak-serdar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. `GetObjectByName` returns `error`.
   So, your `appDeployment` is actually an error
2. You have to access the map by string keys. So, even if `appDeployment` were a valid map, you would have to access `domain_names` by string key.

This should solve both problems:

```
    var obj1 map[string]interface{}

    err = aviClient.AviSession.GetObjectByName("gslbservice", "mygslbname", &obj1)
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
    }
    assert.Equal(t, obj1["domain_names"], "mygslbname")
```

Comment: Now getting error, 
invalid operation: cannot index appDeployment (variable of type error)

Comment: tried your new code snippet and getting below error now.

./avi_learn_test.go:58:9: no new variables on left side of :=
./avi_learn_test.go:62:25: invalid operation: cannot index obj1 (variable of type interface{})

Comment: if I may ask how to assert other data from the map?
such as groups, location etc.
I can do some trial and error and find out too..

Comment: @Simon you can access any value of the map by a string key. e.g. `obj1["domain_names"]`, `obj1["location"]`

Comment: one more small issue,

Error:          Not equal:
                                expected: []interface {}([]interface {}{"helloworldspringbootssl-dit1.xxx.xxx.com"})
                                actual  : string("helloworldspringbootssl-dit1.xxx.xxx.com")

how to match them exactly as I pass?

Answer (score 0):

Is it because `aviClient.AviSession.GetObjectByName` is returning an error? Did you mean to write to `obj1`?

Comment: I think you might be right, Burak also pointed out the same and was chatting through comments.

I tried assert.Equal(obj1.domain_names, "mygslb") and getting error

obj1.name undefined (type interface{} has no field or method name)

Comment: or in other words, how do I print any entries from the map, for eg ttl

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).